# Object identification in Python

Tags: python, memory-usage

In learning Python, I found that when two "names" (or "variables") are assigned to the same value, both of them point to the same memory address. For example

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 10
>>> a is b
True
```

My question is, when assigning `b`, how does Python figure out that a `10` object already exists?

One way might be to create the new object for `b`, scan pre-existing objects in memory to find a duplicate and, if found, point `b` to it. This sounds expensive, and tricky for more complex objects.

Comment: `I found that when two "names" (or "variables") are assigned to the same value, both of them point to the same memory address.` -> This is not true.

Comment: See [Python "is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/306313); you found a CPython implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

It just keeps a cache of small integer instances.

```
>>> a = 58435
>>> b = 58435
>>> a is b
False
```

Precisely how small is [easy to determine manually](http://choorucode.com/2012/05/01/integer-caching-in-python/) for your implementation. Mine caches −5 to 256.

Comment: That is disappointing - I was hoping for something fancy! By the way, it seems `float`s are cached too, e.g. `a = 10245645646.3; b = 10245645646.3; a is b` yields `True`.

Comment: I think recent numbers are also cached. I am getting caching behavior for numbers well outside my caching range (-5 to 256). e.g. `b = 387420489; c = 387420489; b is c` is also `True`. Interestingly, `d = 9**9; d is b` gives `False` even though `d==b` is `True`.

Comment: @wsaleem But if you split into separate lines in the REPL (instead of using the semicolon) you get `False`. But then if you wrap it in a function, you get `True` again. Interesting. May have something to do with the interpreter’s optimizations and with local vs. global variables.

Comment: Related on CodeGolf.SE: [Write a program that makes 2 + 2 = 5](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28851/12166) the tinkering with the integer cache in particular.

Answer (score 0):

`is` operator is not the same as `==`.

While `==` checks the value of object, `is` checks identity of it using it's memory address.

As mentioned before ints from -5 to 256 (inclusive) are special (small) and Python will not recreate those objects. Ints from outside that range will be new objects every time so `is` will return True only if they are the same exact object.

That happens also to: chars, empty strings and some other strings - that looks like Python identifiers.

(I think that bytes as well, but I'm not sure).

If you want to read more, please take a look the fallowing post: http://mrfuxi.github.io/blog/python-gotchas/